# Installing packages on computer in a closed network

Tags: python, pip, package, setuptools

I am not able to install some packages with pip on a computer that has no access to internet.
I have a clean install of python3.10 from source file.
Here is the command I run:

```py
pip3.10 install --no-index --find-links=/path/to/my/local/python-libs --no-cache-dir virtualenv
```

In the directory `/path/to/my/local/python-libs`, I put zip files of package releases:

- setuptools-62.1.0.zip
- virtualenv-20.8.1.zip
- wheel-0.37.1.zip

I have tried the options `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver` but it does not work too.
The error message is:

```
  Processing ./python-libs/setuptools-62.1.0.zip
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Discarding file:///home/user/python-libs/setuptools-62.1.0.zip: Requested setuptools>=41.0.0 from ile:///home/user/python-libs/setuptools-62.1.0.zip has inconsistent version: filename has '62.1.0', but metadata has '62.1.0.post20220423'
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=41.0.0 (from versions: 62.1.0)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=41.0.0
```

I have spent a whole day looking for the causes, maybe it is caused by the new pip resolver or the PEP517, no idea.

Comment: It looks like it's unhappy with your `setuptools` version, as the filename has the version `62.1.0` but the metadata has the version `62.1.0.post20220423`. Where did you download this from?

Comment: I got the zip package from the official Pypa github repository. If you look closely, you'll see that the date of today is added at the end of the version.

Comment: I'm not sure why that occurs but it looks like that is the issue preventing you from using `setuptools`. You could try to use the wheel provided [here](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/62.1.0/#files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to install python moldules without internet, since you have them downloaded already, is to first make a requirements.txt file with the following.

```
setuptools==62.1.0
virtualenv==20.8.1
wheel==0.37.1
```

I just took the version number from your download files

Then go to the dir that have the requirements.txt
run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links --find-links=/path/to/my/local/python-libs
```

note adding the -r requirements.txt allows you to control the version number of the pip packages.

If this doesn't solve the problem then it might be something wrong with your downloaded binaries, try downloading them again but this time use the requirements.txt

```
pip download -r requirements.txt -d binaries
```

This will download the binaries and the versions requested from the requirements.txt into a folder called binaries

Then just try the first command again on your offline machine once you moved the new binaries to the required folder (/path/to/my/local/python-libs) .

Comment: I try with requirements.txt but got the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptool==62.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptool==62.1.0

Comment: I would prefer not using pip download because I find it a bit tedious instead of using zip file.

Comment: I would advice you to download using pip and requirements.txt, if it still doesn't work please let me know

Comment: Also would you mind stating your os in your question?

Comment: ahh sorry spelling mistake setuptools not setuptool

Comment: After fixing the typo: WARNING: Requested setuptools==62.1.0 from file:///home/user/python-libs/setuptools-62.1.0.zip (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)), but installing version 62.1.0.post20220423

Comment: But it works by doing pip download and then pip install using binaries directory. Thanks, but why does it not work with .zip files ?

Comment: might be because you downloaded them from github upstream, so the version data is different

Comment: You are right, the github version of virtualenv is 20.8.1 while on Pypi it is 20.14.1. It seems to work with this last one.

Comment: @dalex78 Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to help other people who encounter this issue find the solution faster